# Chrome popup window focus via global keyboard shortcut on create vs update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Extension testing.

On creating a popup window in a background page command handler triggered by a global keyboard shortcut, when Chrome is not the active app, Chrome does NOT become the active app, the popup window does not have focus.

```
chrome.windows.create({focused: true})
```

But if I immediately do an update after the create, setting focused=true, the popup window becomes active/focused, and on close, the previous focused Chrome window becomes active.

```
chrome.windows.update(window.id, {focused: true})
```

This seems like inconsistent behaviour.

A bug that I should report, or leave it alone and hope the Chrome team don't change it later?

Comment: https://crbug.com - check first if it's reported already.

Comment: I did first, searching on there is painful.